# How to show the iso week number in gcal?

Tags: calendar

Today is 2019-07-17 and I want `gcal` to show the calendar for the current month along with the iso week numbers for the respective weeks.

```
$ gcal --correct-parammeters

      July 2019
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su CW
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 27
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 28
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 29
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 30
 29 30 31             31
```

The correct iso week number for today can easily be confirmed with

```
$ date --date="2019-07-17" +%V
29
```

With `gcal %20190717 --starting-day=Monday` I get the correct order of weekdays but no `CW` column.
Adding `--with-week-number` (or `-K`) gives:

```
     July 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su CW
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 26
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 27
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 28
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
29 30 31             30
```

where the week number is off by one.

There is also `--iso-week-number=yes` but no `CW` column is shown then

Comment: What is your gcal version? for mine (3.6.3) `gcal --with-week-number --iso-week-number=yes` produces a `CW` column with `27` for the *first* week - but then repeats `27` for the second week (and is off by one for the remainder). `gcal --with-week-number --iso-week-number=yes --starting-day=1` appears to work "right" - perhaps this is related? [\[Bug-gcal\] gcal, -K and --iso-week-number](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gcal/2013-01/msg00001.html)

Comment: I misunderstood the documentation and thought `--with-week-number` and `--iso-week-number=yes` where exclusive and never tried both (there really should be an error message when using `--iso-week-number` without `--with-week-number`).   
I have the same gcal version (and the same behaviour for your first command). The second command works for me as well.   
If you turn it into an answer I will accept it.